# How to use sql to find parent directoryId

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have some data in a giant table that looks like this:

```
directoryId Length  Directory
7788    631     Y:\Foo
3606    70246   Y:\Foo\Bar
```

How can I use sql to find the parent folder and provide the parent id?

```
 DirID       ParentDirId   Length         Directory
3606          7788          70246          Y:\Foo\Bar
```

Source Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [Datamap].[SourceFiles](
    [DirectoryID] int IDENTITY(1,1),
    [Length] [float] NULL,
    [Directory] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Extension] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Type] [nvarchar](max) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

I only have a direcotry ID on every row.

So I edited this and my solution.  I have created one table as shown above and it contains data like this:

```
directoryId Length  Directory   Extension   Type
23572   2270    Y:\Data\FS02-V\HarvardPilgrim\Development\Dory\FHCP ICD10   sql Sql Scripts
23572   4396    Y:\Data\FS02-V\HarvardPilgrim\Development\Dory\FHCP ICD10   sql Sql Scripts
23572   1420    Y:\Data\FS02-V\HarvardPilgrim\Development\Dory\FHCP ICD10   sql Sql Scripts
```

Comment: Do you know the ID you are searching for and what are the table names?

Comment: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/17948.t-sql-right-left-substring-and-charindex-functions.aspx

Comment: I have provided what my tables look like @Stivan but I only have a directory ID.  I now want to provide a parent Id.  Im sure I could strip it off of the directory field but I wonder how I would then provide it back to that row.

Comment: Can you show some sample data on two tables

Comment: @TheGameiswar I created a new table instead of having one with every row and another with just the ID's I just created a master source file table with the directory ID already there per my example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possible solution.

```
Declare @YourTable table (directoryId int,Length int, Directory varchar(250))
Insert into @YourTable values
(7788,631,'Y:\Foo'),
(3606,70246,'Y:\Foo\Bar'),
(3607,70246,'Y:\Foo\Bar\SomeDir & Date')



;with cteBase as (
Select A.*
      ,B.*
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (Select Top 1 * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse](Replace(A.Directory,'&','&amp;'),'\') Order By Key_PS Desc) B
)
Select A.directoryId
      ,ParentDirId   =B.directoryId
      ,A.Length
      ,A.Directory
  From cteBase A
  Left Join cteBase B
    on (B.Directory+'\'+Replace(A.Key_Value,'&','&amp;') = Replace(A.Directory,'&','&amp;'))
```

Returns

```
directoryId ParentDirId Length  Directory
7788        NULL        631     Y:\Foo
3606        7788        70246   Y:\Foo\Bar
3607        3606        70246   Y:\Foo\Bar\SomeDir & Date
```

The Parser UDF if needed

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse] (@String varchar(max),@Delimeter varchar(10))
--Usage: Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('Dog,Cat,House,Car',',')
--       Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('John Cappelletti was here',' ')

Returns @ReturnTable Table (Key_PS int IDENTITY(1,1), Key_Value varchar(max))
As
Begin
   Declare @XML xml;Set @XML = Cast('<x>' + Replace(@String,@Delimeter,'</x><x>')+'</x>' as XML)
   Insert Into @ReturnTable Select ltrim(rtrim(String.value('.', 'varchar(max)'))) FROM @XML.nodes('x') as T(String)
   Return 
End
```

Comment: I get this returned:
Msg 9421, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
XML parsing: line 1, character 96, illegal name character

Comment: I think it is because I have an ampersand in one of the directory names, any work arounds?

Comment: @VinnyGuitara Interesting.   Just created a dummy record with an & and got the same error.   Give me a moment

Comment: @VinnyGuitara Updated my answer to trap the &.   Not elegant, but it seems to work.

Comment: OK let me try this.  Thanks!

Comment: This works.  I just have one more question.  How would I deal with a directory whose parent is not listed?  I get a null value.  Will I have to filter on the null values and then create an entry for the null directory or is there a better way to deal with that?

Comment: @VinnyGuitara Good questions.  This is why I opted for the LEFT JOIN.   In my little head, the NULL's should be the top of the hierarchy.  If nothing else, you now know which directories don't chain up; perhaps you can inject the dummy records if needed.

Comment: Thats what I figured.  Thanks so much for the help on this one.